# Sorting dictionary by value and key length

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x, dictionary

I've been googling and seaching and I just cant find an answer.

I have a dictionary which holds the people in the group, and the score the group has, `groups = {"john,alfred,willis":5, "james,connor":5}, ...`. People can be in 2 groups at once, however. What I want to do with this dictionary is sort it by the amount of people AND their score. For example:

```
>>> groups = {"a,b,c":5, "d,e":6, "f,g,h,i":5, "j,k,l":6, "m,n":10, "a,d,f":5}
```

I need to sort it by the score, then by the amount of people, and then by alphabetical order as a final tie breaker. There are no duplicates of groups, however one group may own `"a,b,c,d"` and another may own `"a,b,c,e"`. Higher score trumps lower score, more people trumps less people, and alphabetical order is ... alphabetical order.

```
>>> print(mySort(groups))
"m,n", 10
"j,k,l", 6
"d,e", 6
"f,g,h,i", 5
"a,b,c", 5
"a,d,f", 5
```

The output format doesn't have to be like that, but it is preferred that it is formatted in the way of a dictionary.

I have attempted a few different ways, including splitting the key by `,`'s because the names can be of any length, but because Python isn't my first language, I'm finding it difficult.

**How do you sort dictionaries by value and then key size?**

**EDIT:** I have added another part to the question which I thought I could go without. Turns out it's needed though...

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/ essentially, you can't sort a dictionary, just display it in a sorted fashion.

Comment: Downvoters, explain?. @iwin, how is this a duplicate?

Comment: @iwin, Precision is key, I understand, but you did receive the general gist of what I was requesting, correct?

Comment: I thought it was close enough to the other questions about sorting dictionaries in Python which have many very good answers; I didn't downvote you though.

Comment: which comes first "a,b,c,d" or "a,b,c,e"

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, `"a,b,c,d"` comes first over "a,b,c,e" because d is less than e.

Comment: @iwin, I didn't find the post helpful at all. Because the first part was talking about sorting by keys (which is half my problem), and the second part then starting talking about bictionary-inception in my eyes. I got confused and ran away. :') :/

Comment: so whichever has the highest letter in the alphabet loses the tie?

Comment: Correct. 'a' beats every letter, 'z' loses to every letter.

Comment: ok I added that condition, because we are reversing the sort, we need to negate the value with a `-`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
groups = {"a,b,c":5, "d,e":6, "f,g,h,i":5, "j,k,l":6, "m,n":10}
s = sorted(groups.items(),key=lambda x: (x[1],len(x[0])),reverse=True)

for k,v in s:
    print (k,v)
m,n 10
j,k,l 6
d,e 6
f,g,h,i 5
a,b,c 5
```

use `-max(map(ord,x[0])))` to sort by the  letter that comes latest  in the alphabet, i.e `a,b,c,y` beats `a,b,c,z`.

```
In [37]: groups = {"a,b,c":5, "d,e":6, "f,g,h,i":5, "j,k,l":6, "m,n":10,"a,b,c,d":12,"a,b,c,e":12,"a,b,c,z":13,"a,b,c,y":13}

In [38]: sorted(groups.items(),key=lambda x: (x[1],len(x[0]),-max(map(ord,x[0].split(","))),reverse=True)
Out[38]: 
[('a,b,c,y', 13),
 ('a,b,c,z', 13),
 ('a,b,c,d', 12),
 ('a,b,c,e', 12),
 ('m,n', 10),
 ('j,k,l', 6),
 ('d,e', 6),
 ('f,g,h,i', 5),
 ('a,b,c', 5)]
```

We use the `lambda x: (x[1],len(x[0]),-max(map(ord,x[0].split(","))))` to sort the output above.

In that `x[1],len(x[0])` means we sort first on the values `x[1]` then on the  length of each key `len(x[0])`.

If we are tied on both of those, we go to `-max(map(ord,x[0].split(","))`, the following is an example of how that works:

If we take  `"a,b,c,z" and "a,b,c,y"` as an example and put them in a list `keys =["a,b,c,z","a,b,c,y"]`:

First get the ords of each char:

```
In [54]: ords = [list(map(ord,x.split(","))) for x in keys] # get ord values from each char
In [55]: ords
Out[55]: [[97, 98, 99, 122], [97, 98, 99, 121]]
```

We are sorting  from highest to lowest so we use `reverse = True`.

```
In [56]: sorted([max(x) for x in ords], reverse=True) # puts "z" first because of reversing
Out[56]: [122, 121]
```

So we use `-max(x)` to reverse that output:

```
In [57]: sorted([-max(x) for x in ords], reverse=True) # now "y" comes first
Out[57]: [-121, -122]
```

`x` in the `lambda` is each subitem in `groups.items()` which looks like:

```
([('a,b,c', 5), ('a,b,c,d', 12), ('j,k,l', 6), ('d,e', 6), ('a,b,c,z', 13), ('m,n', 10), ('a,b,c,y', 13), ('a,b,c,e', 12), ('f,g,h,i', 5)])
```

So if we take `('a,b,c', 5)` `x[0] = "a,b,c"` and `x[1] = 5`.

Comment: Tick: In[38] solved all 3 in one hit. You know your Python very well! Thank you. I'll be renaming things so it doesn't look all too obfuscated. I can learn and understand this. If I have questions, I'll be sure to comment. Thank you.

Comment: I will add a bit more when I get back on the comp

Comment: Pretty much everything after lambda. Because I know lambda is an anonymous function, and x is it's parameter.

Comment: `>>> ords = [list(map(ord,x.split(","))) for x in keys]` doesn't work. Apparently map can't take it's passed arguments. `TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 6 found`. Without this sort of code, though, it takes either the largest letter, so 'xys' would trump 'asdz' (while using min instead of -max) (I was quick on the enter key, as usual)

Answer (score 3):

Using [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted): (Return value of the `key` function is used for comparison)

```
>>> groups = {"a,b,c":5, "d,e":6, "f,g,h,i":5, "j,k,l":6, "m,n":10}
>>> sorted_keys = sorted(groups, key=lambda k: (groups[k], k), reverse=True)
>>> sorted_keys
['m,n', 'j,k,l', 'd,e', 'f,g,h,i', 'a,b,c']
>>> [(key, groups[key]) for key in sorted_keys]
[('m,n', 10), ('j,k,l', 6), ('d,e', 6), ('f,g,h,i', 5), ('a,b,c', 5)]
```

**UPDATE**

`key` function should be changed as follow to correctly count people.

```
lambda k: (groups[k], len(k.split(','))), reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

To sort by "amount of people" you rather need

```
>>> sorted(groups.items(), key=lambda p: (p[1], p[0].count(',')), reverse=True)

[('m,n', 10), ('j,k,l', 6), ('d,e', 6), ('f,g,h,i', 5), ('a,b,c', 5)]
```

As a side note, comma-separated strings is not the best way to represent groups of things. Consider making your dict tuple-indexed instead:

```
>>> good_groups = {tuple(k.split(',')):v for k, v in groups.items()}
```

and then

```
>>> sorted(good_groups.items(), key=lambda p: (p[1], len(p[0])), reverse=True)

[(('m', 'n'), 10), (('j', 'k', 'l'), 6), (('d', 'e'), 6), (('f', 'g', 'h', 'i'), 5), (('a', 'b', 'c'), 5)]
```

If your groups are going to be mutated and should be lists, not tuples, you cannot use them as dict keys. Consider a different data structure, for example, a list of dicts:

```
groups = [
   { 'members': ['foo', 'bar'], 'score': 5 },
   { 'members': ['baz', 'spam'], 'score': 15 },
etc
```

Comment: I dislike tuples because they are immutable - it feels like I have no control over them and I would then have to keep creating new tuples if I want to change the contents...

Comment: @mastercork889: hmm.... strings are just as immutable - do you hate them because of this?

Comment: I guess I can't 'hate-on' tuples. I just haven't fully learnt how to use them. I have figured that if you turn a string into a list, it can be mutated, and then pushed back into a string.

Comment: Scary stuff, list/dictionary-inception is. How would I go about getting a value? groups[0][members][1] = bar?